# Attaching a Scala sbt process remotely to Kubernetes with IntelliJ

Tags: azure, scala, kubernetes, intellij-idea, sbt

I have a sbt project running on Kubernetes Cluster (on Azure) and I have an endpoint for it. But I'm a newbie in scala and I want to attach sbt shell from IntelliJ to that endpoint. I tried Remote JVM Debug and gave the cluster IP from Kubernetes services to the corresponding project's code but it gives the error below:

```
Error running 'Debug sbt shell': Cannot connect to remote process. Host is unknown
```

Command line arguments for remote JVM:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:80
```

Debugger mode: `Attach to remote JVM`
Transport: `Socket`

The host IP and port I give is from Kubernetes' services. But It can't be seen in Ingress, instead I have the gateway for the whole project in Ingress with a DNS. It also doesnt work when I use gateway.

Comment: This might give ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60735903/is-it-possible-to-remote-debugging-java-program-in-kubernetes-using-service-name (port forwarding)

Comment: @GaelJ thanks for the comment but I forgot the mension that I'm running the kubernetes cluster in Azure remotely, so I'm not sure that issue is feasible for my case

Comment: @JeredriqDemas If you connect from your local VM to the remote cluster, [`port-forward`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) should work just fine.